# Reading Gmail mails using android SDK

Tags: java, android, sdk, gmail

I want to read Gmail mails in my own android app. Is there anyway to do it using android sdk? If not, what are the other options? parsing gmail atom?

Comment: Development questions are off-topic here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ask and answer that question here.
You need Gmail.java code (in the question there are a link) and you must understand that you shouldn't use that undocumented provider

[Are there any good short code examples that simply read a new gmail message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303805/are-there-any-good-short-code-examples-that-simply-read-a-new-gmail-message)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible using the GMail API, here are some steps I found helpful.

1. Start with the official sample to get the GMailAPI started, see [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/android)
2. When following the instructions I found it helpful to read about the app signing [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html) in order to get Step1+2 in the sample right.
3. With the sample running you can use the information [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) to access messages. You can e.g. replace the implementation in MakeRequestTask.getDataFromApi
4. Be sure to add at least the read-only scope for proper permissions. In the sample the scopes are defined in an array:

   `private static final String[] SCOPES = { GmailScopes.GMAIL_LABELS, mailScopes.GMAIL_READONLY };`
5. My intention was to read all subjects. I used the following code (which is the adapted getDataFromApi method from the official sample):

   ```
    private List<String> getDataFromApi() throws IOException {
        // Get the labels in the user's account. "me" referes to the authentized user.
        String user = "me";
        List<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();

        ListMessagesResponse response = mService.users().messages().list(user).execute();

        for (Message message : response.getMessages()) {

            Message readableMessage = mService.users().messages().get(user, message.getId()).execute();
            if (readableMessage.getPayload() != null) {
                for (MessagePartHeader header : readableMessage.getPayload().getHeaders()) {
                    if (header.getName().compareToIgnoreCase("Subject") == 0) {
                        labels.add(header.getValue());
                   }
               }
           }
       }

       return labels;
   }
   ```