# Recive email java

Tags: android

i am using the default email app that come with ics, and i want to catch the email recieving programatically (i want to recieve and sender information and the email body itself), how can i do it? i tried search however i only find how to send email and how to recieve email in gmail (which is not my case)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to "catch" emails as they come to the phone. You'll have to manually connect to the mail server and download the emails. If you're interested in doing that, I've used the [javamail-android port](http://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/), which actually is pretty fully featured.

Comment: can you understand me how can i catch the email via the "javamail-android port"?can i do that the user will insert the email information(like server and pass and the server ip of his email) and the app will sync with his email? thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, you can do that. I would use [this code](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3303805/1377429) as a starting point (don't forget to fix what he mentions in his answer). You just need to add the jars from the javamail-android site to your project.